# sum() in lambda exercise elaboration needed

Tags: python, loops, sorting, lambda, sum

I was reading about lambda, and even though I can say I understand its purpose, I still can't seem to get further line of code.

Body of the exercise:

> Given a list of strings, sort them according to how many vowels they contain.

code:

```
   def sort_vowel(sequence):
        return sorted(sequence, key=lambda word: sum(v in 'aeiou' for v in word), reverse= True)
```

From here:

lambda initiates 'anonymous function' and takes parameter 'word'. But I can't get how sum() counts vowels in word,

I tried to write it in more generic way:

```
def sort_vowel(sequence):
    for word in sequence:
        for v in word:
            if v in 'aeiou':
                vowels = sum(v)
    return sorted(sequence, key= vowels)
```

What is wrong with this one? I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Anyway what I am trying to understand how does it **summarize elements in string and what is wrong with the function I wrote?**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little "smelly" code as the industry would call it because it is hard to understand for someone not familiar with all of the quirks of Python.

Let's start with the `sorted` part. When you use `key=` in `sorted` it uses that function to produce some output which is compatible by the storing function. In the original case, the function used is a lambda but you could just as easily do this.

```
def count_vowels(word):
    return sum(v in 'aeiou' for v in word)

def sort_vowel(sequence):
    return sorted(sequence, key=count_vowels, reverse= True)
```

Lambdas are just a way to simplify that boilerplate of using `def` and `return` into one statement which possibly returns something.

The next thing that might be confusing: Why does `count_vowels` work?

The main reason it works is because in Python `True` is equal to 1 and `False` is equal to 0.

```
> True + True
2
> False + False
0
```

Thus `(v in 'aeiou' for v in word)` generates a boolean for each letter of the word and `sum` essentially "counts" the `True`s by adding all of the booleans together.

Comment: so basically `sum` can be written as:

`for v in word: if v in 'aeiou': sum(v)?

Comment: @PreacherBaby no. You can’t sum(v) directly because they are strings. The original for loop turns them into Boolean, THEN the sum operation is preformed

Comment: Original loop turns them into Boolean in one-liner? in `v in 'aeiou` part?

Answer (score 1):

The primary error with your code is that you are trying to use the `sum` function on characters. (It's meant for numeric types.)

Another one which doesn't up show up, because the program terminates before it occurs, is that you are passing `vowels` as an argument to the `key` parameter. As it is, it's not clean what the `vowels` object is. The `key` parameter expects a function. Instead of defining one separately, the original program passes it as a lambda.

To see it "written out", consider this example:

```
>>> def count_vowels(word):
...     count = 0
...     for c in word:
...             if c in 'aeiou':
...                     count += 1
...     return count
...
>>> count_vowels('vowel')
2
>>> count_vowels('bcdfg')
0
>>> seq = ['abcde', 'vowel', 'aeiou', 'python', 'uvwxyz']
>>> sorted(seq, key=count_vowels, reverse=True)
['aeiou', 'abcde', 'vowel', 'python', 'uvwxyz']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `lambda word: sum(v in 'aeiou' for v in word)` involves the fact that Booleans have numeric value.

It translates to:

```
def count_vowels(word):
    count = 0
    for v in word:
        if v in 'aeiou':
           count += 1
    return count
```

When that trick and sum are eliminated.

Your function then can be defined as

```
def sort_vowel(sequence):
    return sorted(sequence, key=count_vowels, reverse=True)
```